# Qt creator header files

Tags: qt-creator

I recently switched from Visual Studios 2013 on Windows to Qt Creator on Ubuntu. Where can I find the header files for `algorithm.h` and `math.h`?

In Visual Studios I can simply just go to the Solutions Explorer and look at the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the cursor on `math.h` in `#include <math.h>` then press F2.

STL headers (like algorithm) have no extension in normal systems (i.e. non-MSVC), so `#include <algorithm>` instead of `algorithm.h`.